# Regular redirects in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need a set redirect after word `articles`

For example there URN `/articleswinter/howtodo/`

I need after `articles` put `/`, If there is empty, as a result we should have

`/articles/winter/howtodo/`

thanks

Comment: Please note that you are expected to show your own attempts to solve the issue. We are here to help you fixing your code. We are not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as easy as a simple rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?articles([^/].*)$ /articles/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

An alternative would be to use an explicit rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/articles/
RewriteRule ^/?articles(.*)$ /articles/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Internal Server Error :c

Comment: @k0mar Then you will have to take a look into your http servers error log file to see what the issue is.

Comment: Oh, and please note that I modified the answer after posting it. You might have gotten an endless redirection loop before that modification. So please try the _current_ code as shown in the answer.

Comment: Sad to hear so. And it would be interesting to hear what _exactly_ you mean by "still does not work". But as said before: you probably will have to take a look into your log files which apparently you still have not done. _Why not?_ We cannot do that for you, as much as we would like to help. Until you provide the information in there I am afraid there is nothing more we can do...

Comment: Its okey, I found mistake 
its should be like this
 RewriteRule ^/?articles([^/].*)$ /articles/$1 [R=301,L]

thank u for help :)

Comment: Ah, so you want an external redirect to happen? Sorry, did not read that from your question. But glad to hear that you solved your issue! Have fun!